# Discord.py I want to create a random answer inside of an embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So basically I just want my bot to type different answers but inside an embed, it sounds easy but it's really confusing. I searched for a bit and found nothing so I just thought I could find an answer here. Anything could be helpful and appreciated! Also I want to mention that the code is inside a cog and the error I get after running the code is:

Error N.1: Undefined variable 'responses' [14,17]
Error N.2: Undefined variable 'responses' [24,62]

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

class ppsize(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=['mypp', 'sizepp'])
    async def PPSize(self, ctx):
        pp = discord.Embed(title='PP Size Activated!')
        pp.add_field(name='Measuring your PP... Please wait!', 
        value = responses ['Your PP is 2cm.',
                          'Your PP is 38cm.',
                          'Your PP is 0cm.',
                          'Your PP is too small to be measured.',
                          'Your PP is -16cm.',
                          'Your PP is bigger than a whole house.',
                          'I can not even see your PP mate.',
                          'Your PP is 6cm.',
                          'Your PP is 9cm',
                          'Your PP is 13cm'])
        await ctx.channel.send(embed= pp), (f'{random.choice(responses)}')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(ppsize(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic python question,

```py
responses = [ # Or values, however you want to name it
    'Your PP is 2cm.',
    'Your PP is 38cm.',
    'Your PP is 0cm.',
    'Your PP is too small to be measured.',
    'Your PP is -16cm.',
    'Your PP is bigger than a whole house.',
    'I can not even see your PP mate.',
    'Your PP is 6cm.',
    'Your PP is 9cm',
    'Your PP is 13cm'
]

# To get a random value
import random

random_resp = random.choice(responses)
```

My advice: If you don't know how to define variables you should learn more python before coding discord bots

```py
pp = discord.Embed(title="PP Size Activated!", description="Measuring your PP... Please wait")
pp.add_field(name="Your PP size is...", value=random.choice(responses))

await ctx.send(embed=pp)
```

Comment: Well, I'll take your advice as an important lesson but still, I know how to use the command without an embed but at the current time I'm trying to add this whole code to an embed but I can't do it. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: That's just personal liking, I can edit my answer and add an example if you want, but you should experiment with that

Comment: Oh I see, well I'll try and experiment with similar codes till I get used to them. Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: No worries! Small idea: you can send a message, wait x seconds and edit the message with the PP size

Comment: That's really smart actually... I may try it and see how it goes!